# Where can I find IController for MVC 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
        protected virtual IActionResult InvokeHttp404()
    {
        IController errorController = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<CommonController>();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(HttpContext, routeData));
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

In the new Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, IController could not be found and Execute is not part of IController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one - [Controller](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs) inherits from [ControllerBase](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs).

In your scenario, you would need to resolve a reference to a type of `CommonController` rather than `IController`, with which you can call your action method directly.  Something like;

```
CommonController errorController = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<CommonController>();
errorController.PageNotFound();
return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Stafford!